# Proper use of the * operator in a oneline if statement python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to know if its possible to use the * operator in a oneline if to achieve the following functionality:

```
if node['args'] != None:
    return_val = funct(*node['args'])
else:
    return_val = funct()
```

I thought I could just say

```
return_val = funct(*node['args'] if node['args'] != None else None)
```

but it turns out this is the same as saying

```
if node['args'] != None:
    return_val = funct(*node['args'])
else:
    return_val = funct(*None)
```

which doesn't make any sense for `*None`.

I tired enclosing the first option in parenthesis but this just throws `SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here`

```
return_val = funct((*node['args']) if node['args'] != None else None)
```

Comment: As an aside,it is idiomatic to use the `is` operator for testing `None`, i.e. `if x is None`, or `if x is not None`

Comment: Consider having `node['args']` be an empty sequence instead of `None`. You wouldn't need an `if` check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to provide an *empty sequence*, not `None`:

```
>>> def f(*args):
...     for arg in args:
...         print(arg)
...
>>> x = None
>>> y = ('a','b')
>>> f(*(y if x is not None else ()))
>>> x = object()
>>> f(*(y if x is not None else ()))
a
b
```

But I think your `if -else` statement approach is much preferable. I only have to look at it once and I know immediately what is going on. With the conditional expression, I have to think about it.

Also, this is a *conditional expression*, not a "one-line if statement".

Answer (score 3):

A more concise solution, albeit one with slightly different semantics:

```
return_val = funct(*node['args'] or ())
```

If `bool(node['args'])` evaluates to `False`, the empty tuple `()` will be unpacked (into nothing) and passed; otherwise, `node['args']` will be unpacked and passed.

Answer (score 1):

The `node['args']` can be a `tuple` (or sequence) or `None`.

If your function is defined as follow:

```
def funct(*args):
    return ...
```

You can call it by unpacking `node['args']`.
But, if `node['args']` is `None`, you must replace by the empty tuple `()` (or empty sequence).

You can call your function with `*(node['args'] or ())`, as follow:

```
return_val = funct(*(node['args'] or ()))
```

**Demo**

```
def funct(*args):
    return len(args)


for node in [{'args': (1, 2, 3)}, {'args': None}]:
    return_val = funct(*(node['args'] or ()))
    print(return_val)
```

You get:

```
3
0
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired syntax can be achieved by using logical shortcut:

```
return_val = funct(*node['args'] or ())
```

Of course, `node['args']` should be a sequence or `None`, not, for example, zero.

In Python, `None` is logically `False`, so `or` operation will return the second operand - `()`. If the first argument is not empty, `or` will return it without ever evaluating the second operand.

Also worth noting is that `*` is not an operator. It's a syntax to provide function with positional arguments.